# How to calculate the mean of a fitted gamma distribution?

Tags: scipy, statistics, mean, gamma

I used **scipy.stats.gamma.fit(data)** to fit a gamma distribution to my data. I want to know what the mean of the resulting distribution is.

How do I find the mean of the fitted gamma distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distributions in `scipy.stats` have a `mean` method that (unsurprisingly) computes the mean.

You take the fitted parameters returned by `scipy.stats.gamma.fit` and pass them to `scipy.stats.gamma.mean`:

```
data = stats.gamma.rvs(5, 2, size=1000);  # generate example data

params = scipy.stats.gamma.fit(data)
print(scipy.stats.gamma.mean(*params))
# 6.99807037952
```